# Cartopy image tiles - determining possible zoom level in advance?

Tags: python, tiles, terrain, stamen, cartopy

In Cartopy I'm using an image tile like so:

```
terrain_tile = cimgt.StamenTerrain()
ax.add_image(tile, zoom)
```

By default I've set the zoom level to 14 and that works perfectly for my first test case.

However, for some locations I get "A non-empty list of tiles should be provided to merge". If I change the zoom level to 13 it then works fine.

This seems to be location-based. With some locations having tiles available with a higher zoom level.

Is there a way to determine in advance which zoom levels are available for a particular location?

Comment: There was a feature request for it at https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/315, but for some reason, it got closed. In practice it would be fairly easy to do for a Mercator target, but gets a bit more involved if your projection is anything else.

Comment: Is that the same thing? I'm not talking about automatically selecting a zoom level but rather knowing which are available for slection. Requesting one that's not available cause the code to crash when trying to plot or save a figure.

Comment: Oh, I see. You are right. I wonder if the stamen terrain does not define tiles over the ocean and you are seeing the issue because of that. Do you really want to know if there are *any* tiles in your target domain, or do you really want to know if you have *full* coverage? Either way, there is some code in there for cartopy, but nothing with a particularly inviting API for this yet.

Comment: One of the ones where it fails is over the ocean but another example is over land so this isn't an ocean issue. A tile exists at zoom level 13 and looks correct (but obviously low res). Asking for zoom level 14 (which is my default given my region size) just crashes with the empty tile error. What I'd really like is fallback option where if the requested zoom level doesn't exist, it then increments the level until it can successfully grab one. Alternatively, a way to get a list of possible zoom levels first for that area would be very useful.